# How to activate Python virtual environment in Power BI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, powerbi

Need to use python scripting with Power BI.
All python modules are installed in a virtualenv.
How can this virtualenv be activated?
(Using Python 3 on windows 7)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the Python interpreter in the [Options > Python Scripting settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-python-visuals). There you need to select the Python interpreter `VIRTUALENV\bin\python.exe`.

Comment: Thanks that helped :)